# Have any algorithm or solution for sync 2video playing in a same device-Android

Tags: android, video

I have 2  video playing.How can I sync 2 video to playing in the same time. both video are same time length.
thanks you for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Video playing software doesn't do that. If it's important that they're exactly in sync you need to merge them (eg add a border to A then overlay B) in your favourite video editing software.